# Is there a direct way to select the buffer displayed in a non-active window?

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, vim-windows

I usually have two windows open, one in which I'm working and one in which I'm viewing some information (compiler messages, relevant library headers, etc. etc.). Now, it's easy to switch the buffer *on which I'm working* with `:b`, which offers nice tab-completion – however, that's not actually necessary very often since I usually spend substantial time working on a single file. What's needed more often is switching the buffer in the *other* window, however to do that I now use the pretty awkward `^w p` `:b foo` `^w p` combination.

Is it possible to choose that buffer *without* actually switching to the other window and then back again?

Comment: Incidentally, the Emacs shortcut for this action is `^x 4 b`.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
function! ChangeWindow(buf)
    execute "wincmd p"
    execute "e " . a:buf
    execute "wincmd p"
endfunction

command! -complete=buffer -nargs=1 CW call ChangeWindow("<args>")
```

You create a function `ChangeWindow()` which takes as argument a buffer name and execute the commands you usually do manually (<kbd>ctrl+p</kbd>, `:e newBuf`, <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd>)

You also create a command with `-complete=buffer` so it will provide the same autocompletion as `:b` and it will call the function with the argument to gave.

This way you only have to do `:CW foo` to put the buffer `:foo` in the previous window.

Comment: That works very nicely, though I would prefer something that'll work out of the box without my custom `.vimrm`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm not aware of a build-in feature which would allow you to do that but maybe someone will prove me wrong :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a limited amount of buffers to cycle through instead of needing to open a specific buffer or file you could use `:bnext` or some variant of that. If you combine that with a `:map`-variant and some window switching you could get this:

```
nnoremap <F8> <C-W>w:bnext<CR><C-W>W
nnoremap <S-F8> <C-W>w:bprevious<CR><C-W>W
```

Here <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift-F8</kbd> will be mapped to cycled forward or backwards between the buffers in the *next* window.

Add that to your `.vimrc` and you are good to go. If you do not want to do that just add it as a regular command.